# Self defined __repr__ for pretty print in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree, repr

I have got a piece of code from [here](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/2921219.html), about using the `__repr__` to get kind of pretty print. However, I want to modify this code, because while using it in a loop, I always got error:  `maximum recursion depth exceeded`

The problem is, I do not know how to modify it, because I do not understand this self-defined `__repr__` clearly, even I have read some of explanations from [here](http://glue.jjj.sun.ac.za/%7Ejames/IntroPython/trees.html).

Code:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret
```

My quesiton:

1. is the `repr` the same as the `__repr__` in the recursion?
2. is the variable `level` indicates the `recursion` depth?
3. what is the purpose of this line `ret += child.__repr__(level+1)` ?

My purpose of using this code: to traverse a tree and print somewhat like follows:

```
'grandmother'
    'daughter'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
    'son'
        'granddaughter'
        'grandson'
```

Very confused about the recursion part, appreciate any comment, thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not recursion, because even if `child` is (as expected) an instance of `node`, each bound method is a separate callable. For all practical purposes, though, you can think of it as recursion.

Comment: `repr(self.value)`, though, is `self.value.__repr__`, which is absolutely *not* recursion, assuming `self.value` is not an instance of `node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repr` doesn't do anything except call its argument's `__repr__` method. Since `self.value` is likely *not* an instance of `node`, `self.value.__repr__` is not a recursive call.

`child.__repr__`, for all practical purposes, *is* a recursive call, so you are correct that `level` is a measure of the "depth" of the current call in the recursion tree.

`ret` is just the concatenation of each child's representation. Those, combined with the representation of the root, produces the representation of the entire tree rooted at the current node.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chepner, if the `level` is a measure of `depth`, it seems that there is no limitation on the `depth` in the code, will the `exceed its max depth` situation happen?

Comment: It's possible, but unless your tree is huge and/or unbalanced, the depth is unlikely to be anywhere near 1000. You need around 4 billion nodes to make a balanced tree have a depth of even 32.